# Rails merging tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, merge

I have two tables: `Members and Addresses`. How can I merge these two tables together in my model, so that I could combine all their columns together? For example, Members has a column named `position` and Addresses has a column named `street`. How could I make it so that I could have Position and Address in the same virtual table. Is there a merge function for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to create a separate model, you can use the basic Ruby constructs for this:

I'll assume `Member` has a column called `address_id`, that is a member `belongs_to` an `Address`. This will automatically associate the joins for you.

So all you need to do is something like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
end

member = Member.create(:address => Address.find(123))
```

If you want to get the address and just the position field then go:

```
member = Member.find(456)
position = member.address.position
```

or perhaps:

```
Member.joins(:address).select("members.position, addresses.street")
```

Not sure what you are trying to do, but if it is something very specific, you could also try creating a View in your database and then making a model for it, treating it like a regular table.

Comment: Well basically when an order form is filled out for my site, you have to fill out the address for the business and then the address for each member in the business. I thought it would be maybe a little less redundant if I did it this way... Do you agree or am i just using bad practice right now?

Comment: If you have a hard time doing it in Rails, you are probably not doing it the way Rails wants you to do it. I'd go with the simplest approach. What you might actually want is a has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through relationship. I'm still not sure 100% what you are trying to accomplish.